# Icons images are not appearing when using Tab in MAUI on Android

Tags: android, tabs, maui

I am trying to add Tabbar with Tabs on my MAUI application and it's works fine with displaying and navigating between pages. But for some reason I just can't get images to show in the Tab Icon property. I am only getting a round dot. Though I've noticed that if I reference the image wrongly the dot disappears.

[image]

I've seen some YouTube videos, I've followed the Microsoft Fundamentals for Shell tabs, I've tried using other icons and extensions, and I've tried adding the Icons to the ShellContent but I am still only getting the round dot.

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Counter" 
             Icon="counter.png">
            <ShellContent
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Log"
             Icon="log.png">
            <ShellContent
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Log}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="About"
             Icon="about.png">
            <ShellContent 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:About}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

The icons work perfectly if I'm using the regular ShellContent without Tab or TabBar.

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Counter"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Icon="counter.png"
        Route="MainPage" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="Log"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Log}"
        Icon="log.png"
        Route="Log" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="About"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:About}"
        Icon="about.png"
        Route="About" />
</Shell>
```

The only thing I have'nt tried which is being used on Microsoft Fundamentals is `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"` but one of the YouTube videos were also not using this MVVM pattern.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Given that icon works in one place, but not in tabbar/tab, smells like it might be a Maui bug. But I haven't tried icons there, so I'm just speculating. Did you try on Windows, to see if they work there?

Comment: Just seems odd that noone has reported it yet although you might be right. Alas the Windows Machine won't run and I cant figure out exactly which setting I need to check to make it work. It pops up say that "A debugger is attached to MyApp.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception". I've read it might be a setting in Debug ->Windows -> Exception Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the android doesn't support setting a color image as the tab icon. I have tried your code with the two kinds of image. There is my code:

```
 <TabBar>
        <Tab
            Title="Home"
            Icon="first.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab  Title="NewPage"
        Icon="second.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        Icon="first.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="NewPage"
        Icon="second.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}"
        Route="NewPage1" />
```

And the reslut with the color image:

[image]

[image]

The icon getting a round dot if the image is a color image.

The reslult with the black and white picture:

[image]

[image]

The icon can show correctly both in the flyoutitem and the tabbar.

Comment: You are exactly right. I removed the background of an image leaving only white color icon and now i see it correctly. Nicely found. :) This sort of thing should've been mentioned in the Microsoft Fundamentals for Shell tabs.