# Why aren't the icons shown in a TabBar in MAUI?

Tags: maui, tabbar, maui-windows

I have the following TabBar and, according to Microsoft documentation, the icons should just be shown:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Icon="home.png" Title="Home">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Icon="home.png" Title="Garden">
        <ShellContent Title="Garden" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Garden}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The icon is located in the Resources/Images folder and is of type "MauiImage" [image: Icon location]

When building it for Windows, I am expecting the icons to be shown, instead squares are displayed in their place:
[image: IconResult]

Am I missing something or how can I make the icons be shown?

Comment: The solution is the accepted answer from this other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248429/icons-images-are-not-appearing-when-using-tab-in-maui-on-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should use a `black` and `white` image and the icons would be shown. Secondly, you may need the icon with `svg` format and then consume it in `png`. I used the default svg file: **dotnet_bot.svg** in the Resources/Images folder. It can show the icons as expected.

Below is the running output and xaml for your reference:

[image]

```
    <TabBar> 
        <Tab Icon="dotnet_bot.png"    Title="Home" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>


        <Tab Icon="dotnet_bot.png"  Title="Garden">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer!

What you write is correct, but it didn't solve my problem. It seems that the issue is that the image is a color one. If I use a black and white image, the icons are shown.

Discovered the solution in the answer of another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248429/icons-images-are-not-appearing-when-using-tab-in-maui-on-android