# C# MAUI ShellContent Icon

Tags: c#, shell, tabs, icons, maui

When I set an icon through the Icon property in the  tag, the icon is painted in a different color and the original color of the icon (multi-colored) is lost. How to fix this? A png icon without a background. With a background only a black square is obtained

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Domestic"
              Icon="paw.png"
              
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}">
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png"></Image>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="Monkeys"
              Icon="dotnet_bot.png"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
</TabBar>

[original icon][1]
[changed icon][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDq8e.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNO1K.png
```

Comment: May I know what platform you are targeting? Also, do you mean the color of the icon for the bottom tabs?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Targeting platform Android Api 29 Yes icons for the bottom tabs are changed too

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can reproduce the issue and it seems it doesn't support set a colored image as the tab icon on Android. see [this answered thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75279791/9644964). However, for the flyout icon, it can be rendered as expected.